# Conky infobar alignment left and right

Tags: conky

I want to build a simple infobar using conky. Take the following example:

[image]

`dropbox zotero` should be aligned to the left.

`SSID: Hier Volume...` should be aligned to the right.

Currently I am working with `{offset 800}` to move the second output to the right. However, this is very inflexible when the right output changes. Sometimes it exceeds my screen.

`.conkyrc`:

```
background yes
use_xft yes
xftfont Noto Sans:size=10
xftalpha 1
update_interval 1
total_run_times 0
# Run in own window
own_window yes
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_type desktop
# Don't show in window lists and on all desktops
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_colour white
double_buffer yes
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
default_color black
alignment tl
maximum_width 1280
minimum_size 1280
gap_x 0
gap_y 2
no_buffers yes
uppercase no
cpu_avg_samples 2
override_utf8_locale no

##############################################
#  Output
##############################################

TEXT
  ${exec basename $(ps -efa | grep dropbox |grep -v 'grep ' | awk '{print $NF}')} \
  ${exec basename $(ps -efa | grep zotero |grep -v 'grep ' | awk '{print $NF}')} \
  ${offset 800} ${battery BAT0} \
  SSID: ${wireless_essid wls1} \
  Volume: ${exec amixer -c 0 get Master | grep Mono: | awk '{print $(NF-2)}'} ${exec amixer -c 0 get Master | grep Mono: | awk '{print $NF}'} \
  Keyboard: ${exec setxkbmap -print | awk -F"+" '/xkb_symbols/ {print $2}'} \
  ${time %H:%M} \
  ${time %a %d %b %Y}
```

Comment: Have you tried `$alignr` in place of `${offset 800}`? This is an example line from my .conkyrc, which displays "Hostname" on the left and the result on the right: `Hostname: $alignr$nodename`

Comment: Thanks Ash. I was playing with the `$alignr` setting before but replacing `${offset 800}` with it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ash said in the comments, the way to do this is `$alignr`/`$alignl`. Something like:

```
TEXT
  ${exec basename $(ps -efa | grep dropbox |grep -v 'grep ' | awk '{print $NF}')} \
  ${exec basename $(ps -efa | grep firefox |grep -v 'grep ' | awk '{print $NF}')} \
  $alignr  ${battery BAT0}   SSID: ${wireless_essid wlan0} Volume: ${exec amixer -c 0 get Master | grep Mono: | awk '{print $(NF-2)}'} ${exec amixer -c 0 get Master | grep Mono: | awk '{print $NF}'} \
  Keyboard: ${exec setxkbmap -print | awk -F"+" '/xkb_symbols/ {print $2}'} \
  ${time %H:%M} \
  ${time %a %d %b %Y}
```

Comment: There is no `$alignl` in Conky v1.12.2 (current in ubuntu) nor in 1.15 (latest on github)

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that to align LEFT, you just need to remove any `${alignr}` and `${alignc}` from your line.